# Language magento 1.9 description by admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, language

I have 2 stores., one store has 2 store view (english, french) & other store has 3 store view (english, french, german). I add the description of products manually by admin panel according to the language one by one. Is there any way to add description in the first store (french) & then the description automatically add in second store (french).

Comment: Do you mean that it automatically translates it for you?

Comment: Not automatically... if there is 2 french store view...if i add manually in one by admin panel  then other french store view also get the same description...

Comment: Ah ok i get it, you can import all you descriptions and use the french one as default. Maybe create a csv with all your descriptions and then run an import on both stores